# Oauth 2.0 Error LinkedIn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I have been using oauth 2.0 with Linkedin as the provider. Now as of today suddenly the authentication is no longer working. Looked on Linkedin its API profile page and figured that they have been updating their program.

The error that I am getting is the following:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

This is in JS in the Console. I am wondering if this is the actual error or if there is another error.

I am using Rails on the back-end

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn February 12th 2015 update effects LinkedIn applications between May 12th - May 19th, 2015. Maybe, your application affected today.

I'm getting error after updating. Your application has not been authorized for the scope "r_fullprofile". The update affected somethings.

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Comment: I keep being kicked out. Also linkedin now took some things away. Agreed on your analysis, but not the whole storey.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Not only on linkedin side, but also in your initializers you have to be careful with what you are asking for. So r_fullprofile is not longer part of Linkedin API (you have to ask linkedin to be able to make it work). There are also other API things that no longer work (e.g. r_connections), so be really careful as Linkedin has changed this policy.

In addition, you should not forget to reset the server to reinitialize the initializers.