# LinkedIn oAuth1 always return 'Member xxx does not have permission to get company xxx' after May 2015

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api, restsharp

we have a portal to fetch 'num-followers' and working well, but after the linkedin upgrading, we encounter following 403 message:

```
<error>
  <status>403</status>
  <timestamp>1440149000543</timestamp>
  <request-id>ULRPYICAEE</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Member xxxx does not have permission to get company xxxx</message>
</error>
```

after the research as linkedin said:
"*New requirement for Companies API
All calls to Companies API endpoints will require the authenticated user to be flagged as an administrator of the LinkedIn Company Page that is the target of the API call.  You become the administrator of a page when you create it.  If the page already exists, you will have to contact the existing administrator to grant admin access to other LinkedIn members.
Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the appropriate admin permission interact with the target company.*"

so we upgrade the member to be as administrator of company page, then we test by the https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console, using Oauth2

1. Check if the member is a company administrator, **yes**
2. Get a company's followers, by segment, **successfully**

but the original code in our portal still encounter the same 403 error, does linkedin abandoned oauth1.0? do i missed some config setting?

thanks in advance if anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn February 12th 2015 update effects LinkedIn applications between May 12th - May 19th, 2015. Maybe, your application affected today.

Check the following answer please.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208638/741356